# VS Code: automatic file upload (deployment) via SSH from Windows

Tags: ssh, web-deployment, vscode-extensions

So I installed the cool SSH extension in VS Code (Windows).
Works fine.
But I have no intention working on the linux server. I simply like to synch my files.
And - as shown in numerous tutorials - I can upload files to my remote servers simply by drag & drop.
Now - I neither need FileZilla to deploy my build nor do I need to launch MobaXterm to connect to those servers lacking FTP.

But seriously - drag & drop?
There must be a way to automate this.
Can I do this with npm - or the PowerShell?